# Variable declaration and definition

Tags: c, declaration, definition

```
int x;
```

Is this a declaration or a definition?

As I write the following code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("%p",&x);
    return 0;
}
```

it prints some address. So as memory is allocated, `int x;` can't be just a declaration. So is it a definition?

Comment: This is very vague.  I don't undertand the question very well.

Comment: Also, this code might give you a segfault depending on what platform you are running it on.

Comment: @krico: The question is precise.

Comment: Use the conversion character "%p" to print pointers that you cast to (void*), otherwise casting a pointer to an integer type might lead to undefined behavior. (If you really can't avoid, cast pointers to `uintptr_t`, if it exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [C standard (n1256)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.7 Declarations**
> ...
> 5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A *definition* of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> — for a function, includes the function body;<sup>101)</sup>
> — for an enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the
> identifier.

In this case, `int x;` is a definition (or a defining declaration).

Answer (score 2):

`int x`; is a definition. `extern int x;` is just a declaration. `extern int x = 3;` is also a definition. HTH

Comment: As he's just taking the address of the variable, I don't see why this is UB.

Comment: @Job, oh, sorry, didn't see that

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan I'm trying to show that the compiler allocates memory for int x;

Comment: It is UB to use an uninitialized pointer in any context, even without dereferencing it, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @R.. No, this isn't an unitialized pointer. This is well defined because we have an uninitialized variable and are just taking its address

Comment: It isn't an uninitialised pointer, just an uninitialised variable but that is still undefined behaviour. One reason is that - though not very common now - parity protected memory may be being used so that a hardware exception can be raised to signal certain types of memory errors (e.g. bits changed by cosmic rays). Where parity protection is used it is quite common to have to write to a location first to set the parity correctly before doing a read.

Comment: Yes it might be undefined behavior to convert an address to an integer, if the address does not fit: "Except as previously specified, the
result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
type."

Comment: Use the conversion character "%p" to print pointers that you cast to `(void*)`.