# Declaration or Definition in C

Tags: c, declaration, definition

From [External Variables Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable):

> If neither the extern keyword nor an
>   initialization value are present, the
>   statement can be either a declaration
>   or a definition. It is up to the
>   compiler to analyse the modules of the
>   program and decide.

I was not able to fully grasp the meaning of this statement with respect to C. For example, does it imply that:

```
int i;
```

is not necessarily a declaration (as I have been assuming until now), but could be a definition as well (by definition of Definition & Declaration on the same webpage, no puns intended)?

In a nutshell, is the above statement:
a. just a declaration, or
b. declaration +  definition?

Reference: [Variable declaration and definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4012724/191776)

**Summary of answers received:**

> ```
>                          Declaration    Definition    Tentative Definition   Initialized 
> int i;   (inside a block)    Yes           Yes                No                No
> int i=5; (inside a block)    Yes           Yes                No               Yes(to 5)
> int i;   (otherwise)         Yes            No               Yes               Yes(to 0)
> extern int i;                Yes            No                No                No
>
>
> All definitions are declarations but not vice-versa.
> ```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C standard says that

> **A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier** that: for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object (…)

Definitions encompass declarations, i.e., every definition is necessarily a declaration, so it doesn’t make sense to say that

```
int i;
```

is not a declaration. It *is* a declaration which also happens to be a definition. Or, it is a definition, hence a declaration.

Comment: However, it's a good idea to keep in mind that not all declarations are definitions.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming it's at file scope it's a 'tentative definition'. From 6.9.2/2 "External object definitions":

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
>   tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.

This means that it would be valid to also have the following in the translation unit:

```
int i = 42;
```

since that declaration has an explicit initializer, it's the definition of the variable `i`.

As far as if the declaration is in a block scope, the standard says the following (6.2.2/2 "Linkages of identifiers"):

> Each declaration of an identifier with
>   no linkage denotes a unique entity.
>
> ...
>
> *(paragraph 6)*  The following
>   identifiers have no linkage: ... a
>   block scope identifier for an object
>   declared without the storage-class
>   specifier extern.

So in block scope, the declaration would be a definition as well.

Comment: Assuming it is within a block (not file scope)...?

Comment: @crypto: updated the answer to cover a block scope declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've selected Bavarious' answer as it is more direct.

Comment: @crypto: the detail to keep in mind is that seeing `int i;` might give one the impression that `i` is initialized to `0` - but that might not be the case.

Comment: I have added that in the summary now, please edit it if incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of variables:

- A declaration of a variable is a statement which describes how this variable looks like. So:

  ```
  extern int x;
  ```

  in global scope translates to: "somewhere in the code, there's a variable called `x` which has type `int` and extern linkage. A declaration is necessary before you ever refer to `x`. (The same goes to function declarations.)
- A definition is a statement which creates an instance of this variable. So:

  ```
  int x;
  ```

  in global scope creates a single variable of type `int` with extern linkage. So if you'd put that line in a header, every translation unit including that header would try to create its own copy of `x`, which is undesirable - that's why we only have declarations in header files. The same goes to functions: if you provide the function body, it's a definition.

Also, formally, every definition is a kind of declaration, as it also has to specify how this variable/function looks like - so if a definition already exists in a given scope, you don't need any additional declarations to use it.

Answer (score 1):

From the C99 spec:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>      without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
>         tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>            identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>                 the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>                  identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>                   equal to 0.

So this is one case in which a simple declaration without an initializer can be a declaration.

Comment: Is it possible for you to append your answer to Michael's, as you are referring to the same part of the C99 Standard?

Comment: That quote from the spec is talking about compiler behavior. It is saying that this particular case of declaration might end-up being a definition.

Comment: ITYM the last word to be "definition"

Answer (score 1):

As C uses the terms:

A "definition" creates something (which occupies some sort of memory). It also describes something. This means a "definition" is also a "declaration".

A "declaration" just describes something. The idea is that the compiler needs to know how to build the code that uses the thing defined elsewhere. Later, the linker then links the use to the something.

Declarations allow you to compile code and link it (later) as a separate step.