# How is the value of global variable changing in my code?

Tags: c, global-variables

I have declared global variable again after the main function but It still affects main function. I know that C allows a global variable to be declared again when first declaration doesn’t initialize the variable(It will not work in c++). If I assign the value after the main function it still works with two warning in c but gives error in c++.

I have debugged the code but it never reaches the line `int a=10;`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int a;

int main()
{
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
/*a=10  works fine with following warnings in c.
        warning: data definition has no type or storage class
        warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'a' [-Wimplicit-int]|

        but c++ gives the following error
        error: 'a' does not name a type|
*/
int a=10;
```

The output is `10`.

Comment: Hi, Whats the purpose of re declaration of 'a'  at the end?

Comment: This will surely help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388431/declaring-two-global-variables-of-same-name-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C Standard#6.9.2p2

> 2 A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a **tentative definition**.....

So, this

```
int a;
```

is tentative definition of identifier `a`.

Couple of points about *tentative definition*:

- If there are no definitions in the same translation unit, then the tentative definition acts as an actual definition with the initializer `= 0`.
- If an actual external definition is found **earlier or later in the same translation unit**, then the tentative definition just acts as a declaration.

In your program, compiler found the definition of `a` in the same translation unit:

```
int a=10;
```

Hence, you are getting the output `10` when compiling with C compiler.

Now, regarding the error when compiling with C++ compiler:

If you have this statement in your program:

```
a=10;
```

This will give error when compile with C++ compiler because you are missing the type specifier which is required. But this code will compile with C complier because, in older version of C (C89/90), if the type specifier is missing then it will default set to `int`. Of course, you will get warning message when compile with C99 & C11 compiler because this implicit declaration is no longer supported.

If you have this statement in your program:

```
int a=10;
```

C++ does not have concept of *tentative definitions* and `int a;` is definition in C++. Hence, due to concept of [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) the C++ compiler will give error - `redefinition of 'a'`.

Answer (score 7):

Several things:

- The first `int a;` is a tentative declaration; the second `int a = 10;` is a defining declaration.
- `a` is declared at file scope, so it will have `static` storage duration - this means that storage for it will be set aside and initialized at program startup (before `main` executes), even though the defining declaration occurs later in the source code.
- Older versions of C allow for implicit `int` declaration - if a variable or function call appears without a declaration, it is assumed to have type `int`. C++ does not support implicit declarations, so you will get an error.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
int a; /* global declaration */
```

compiler treats above statement as just a *declaration* *not definition*. It looks for definition of `a` in other translation units, it finds below `main()` as

```
int a=10;
```

Hence the output `10`.

To avoid warnings, declare `a` with `extern` storage class for e.g

```
extern int a;
```

Comment: Because C++ is a different language from C, despite bearing many similarities.

Comment: Since `C++` is strictly type checking, it gives error. Declare with `extern` C++ will allow it.

Answer (score 0):

all i know, today's c++ compiler cannot run the code:

```
int a;
int main()
{
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
int a=10;
```

nor

```
int a;
int main()
{
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
a=10;
```

because c++ detects double declaration of variable.
and
because it cannot initialize a variable outside a method.

error "'a' does not name a type" is because of that (the second) error, c++ expect the first word to be a type for declaration (ex: int, long, char, -etc-), and variable is given.